# Approximating object statistics with Django

Tags: django

If I had say 70,000 objects and wanted to do statistics on them, but the statistics didnt need to be 100% accurate, what is the best way to pull out say 1,000 objects, do statistics on those objects and then just scale it to approximate the statistics for the 70,000? I can't quite seem to find an efficient way to get 1000 random objects from a queryset.

Answer (score 1):

You can get random objects with:

```
objs = list(MyModel.objects().order_by("?")[:1000])
```

But the underlying `order by random` that gets generated for the SQL isn't particularly efficient.

Comment: That is exactly what I ran into. The documentation I have read said that .order_by('?') is slow, which doesnt help if I am trying to speed things up by taking a sample set.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but sometimes when doing heavy reporting you need more than Django's ORM can offer. I worked with a guy who used Django for his main application, but for some reporting tools (and a JSON service) he used Flask and SQLAlchemy and was able to accomplish a whole lot more and without having to write SQL.

Answer (score 0):

there is a [great post](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/getting-random-rows-postgresql-django) on the issue of getting random rows from the database (there are few good points in the comments too).

the only thing I would check is to get some objects by "in_bulk" method, because you may be even faster this way.